# Generated Update by Grails - unable to delete if item is 'xitem'

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails

Grails

```
def update(Bookmark bookmark) {

if (params.item) {
    def portfolio = Portfolio.read(params.item)
    bookmark.addToItems(portfolio.id)
    bookmark.addToPortfolios(portfolio.id)
} else if (params.xitem) {
    bookmark.removeFromItems(params.xitem)
    bookmark.removeFromPortfolios(portfolio.id)
}

try {
    println " Validate? " + bookmark.validate()
    bookmark.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
} catch (e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    log.error e
    respond e
    return
}

def item = [:]
item.name = bookmark.name
item.id = bookmark.id
item.items = bookmark.items ?: []
item.portfolios = bookmark.portfolios ?: []
item.added = true

respond item
```

}

JQuery

```
$('.box').on('click', '.icn-close-white', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    deleteBookmarkItem( $(this), $(this).parent().attr('data-portfolio-id'), $(this).parent().attr('data-bookmark-id') );
});

function deleteBookmarkItem( btn, itemID, bookmarkID ) {
    var sendData = {
        xitem: itemID,
        ownerId: userSessionId
    };


    $.ajax({
        url: '/api/bookmarks/'+ bookmarkID + '?' + $.param( sendData ),
        type: 'PUT',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function( response ) {
            //unlink or remove portfolio from bookmark
            $('[data-portfolio-id="'+itemID+'"]').remove();
            console.log(response);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Stacktrace: no such property: portfolio for class.

Portfolio id is itemId and bookmark id is bookmarkID. The update is generated by grails for bookmark so if use xitem, it should be able to remove portfolio id from bookmark list. I also tested by commenting out the "  bookmark.removeFromPortfolios(portfolio.id) " line and it removes item but when refresh, item is still there.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding 
Stacktrace: no such property: portfolio for class.

It's normal because you are referring to portfolio object which is not defined in *else if* block(defined in *if* block only).
I guess you need to change your code to

```
if (params.item) {
    def portfolio = Portfolio.read(params.item)
    bookmark.addToItems(portfolio.id)
    bookmark.addToPortfolios(portfolio.id)
} else if (params.xitem) {

    def portfolio = ...//get portfolio instance or only portfolio.id  here 

    bookmark.removeFromItems(params.xitem)
    bookmark.removeFromPortfolios(portfolio.id)
}
```

regarding  *it removes item but when refresh, item is still there.*
try to change

```
bookmark.save(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

to

```
bookmark.merge(failOnError:true, flush:true)
```

Comment: thanks. I tried "def portfolio = Portfolio.get(params.id)" but it is still not getting anything. Also I tested merge and the items still come back after refresh